# Strange decreasing of value

Tags: c++

Okay, so I am trying to convert part of an array in a number and "cout" it, but when I am doing it, it suddenly decreases sometimes.

```
int c                   = 0;
unsigned long long nnum = 0; 

for (int i = 1; i <= numsize; i++)
{
    if ((i <= li) || (i >= ri))
    {
        // in my example li=4,ri=6, i skip element [5]
        // anum is reversed array of digits in the number
        nnum += anum[i] * (pow(10, c++));
        cout << nnum << ' ' << anum[i] << ' ' << anum[i] * pow(10, c - 1)
             << endl;  // checking
    }
}
cout << nnum;
return 0;
```

copy of my console:

Enter a number: 12300980

0 0 0

80 8 80

979 9 900

979 0 0

30978 3 30000

230978 2 200000

1230978 1 1e+006

1230978

as you can see, first step is last digit 0, nnum is 0, we added 0. next one we add 80 (80*10^1), we get 80. next step we add 900 and get 979, why?
it decreases one more time then... have absolutely no idea.

UPD: all the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long num,nnum;
    int numsize=0;
    int anum [1000]={0};
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>num;
    int c=1;
    while (num>0) {
        numsize++;
        anum[c++]=num%10;
        num=num/10;
    }
    int mind=10,maxd=-1,mini,maxi;
    for (int i=numsize;i>=1;i--) {
        if (anum[i]<mind) {
            mind=anum[i];
            mini=i;
        }
        if (anum[i]>maxd) {
            maxd=anum[i];
            maxi=i;
        }
    }
    int li=min(maxi,mini);
    int ri=max(maxi,mini);
    c=0;nnum=0;
    for (int i=1;i<=numsize;i++) if ((i<=li)||(i>=ri)) {
        nnum+=anum[i]*(pow(10,c++));

        cout<<nnum<<' '<<anum[i]<<' '<<anum[i]*pow(10,c-1)<<endl;
    }
    cout<<nnum;
    return 0;
}
```

full task is to enter number, convert it to array, then convert everything not between first maximum and first minimum back to a number and cout it.

Comment: Could you post a code example long enough for us to compile and test?

Comment: Hard to tell if that's your problem without seeing the whole thing, but: `pow()` returns a floating point value, not an integer, which brings precision issues alongside it.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez done

Comment: Works fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/pdFWDLFdlthBqiv4, which architecture/compiler are you using?

Comment: @Frank codeblocks 17.12 gnu gcc compiler, c++11

Comment: Don't forget that array indexes are *zero* based. Using one-based indexes requires your arrays to be larger than needed, and will irritate all your fellow programmers, not to mention for larger multi-people projects if your code is the only using one-based indexes the code-base will be impossible to understand and maintain and give you errors that are hard to track down. Also remember documentation (comments), what is the code doing? Why is it doing that? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You show the actual output from some specified input, and that's good, but what output did you expect?

Comment: @НеизвестныйНеизвестный Thanks for the info, but we are going to need much more details, I'm afraid: which version of GCC? What OS are you using? What kind of CPU are you compiling this for? 32/64 bits? X86/ARM? (either that, or just try replacing `pow()` on your end and see if it fixes it)

Comment: @Frank yes i replaced it with my function with for and it's working. interesting. BTW why pow (int,int) does return float?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for info, i am only a beginner either in c++ and in stackoverflow)

Comment: Even when `pow` takes an int it returns a double because double is less prone to overflow

Comment: I see. Didn't encounter that before. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Despite using only integers for your `pow()`, the function itself is calculated using `double` types and calculates the power using polynomial. Depending on your architecture and compiler, if you do like `pow(10, 2)` you might arrive to `99.9999999..` which, at the end of calculation and truncated to `int` will give you `979`

Either round your result (before converting to `int`), or, for speed reasons, come up with you own `power()` function if the goal to use it only for integers